# Python program runs with 'python3 progfile.py' but fail to start as service

Tags: python-3, services

I installed a python program from a github repo with an automatic script. It is configured to launch itself as a service on startup, and everything seems working fine. I edited the 'py' file to change and improve program, but when I save it I cannot start it anymore as service. If I ask for status it says

```
Process: 593 ExecStop=/usr/bin/curl http://127.0.0.1/save (code=exited, status=7)
Process: 591 ExecStart=/opt/hue-emulator/HueEmulator3.py (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

Instead, if I try to launch directly using:

```
sudo python3 /opt/hue-emulator/HueEmulator3.py
```

everything seems to works fine. What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
This is the repo: https://github.com/diyhue/diyHue
and this is the `systemctl cat hue-emulator.service` output

```
[Unit]
Description=Hue Emulator Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
StartLimitInterval=200
StartLimitBurst=5

WorkingDirectory=/opt/hue-emulator
ExecStart=/opt/hue-emulator/HueEmulator3.py
ExecStop=/usr/bin/curl http://127.0.0.1/save
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It seems the simple file editing cause this issue. I tried to resinstall via script, then simple add a space then save and it will not run anymore as service.
To edit I use notepad++ on Windows using a shared folder via Samba.
I also tried to check permissions before and after and I got:

```
-rwxr-xr-x (before)
-rw-r-xr-x (after)
```

I fixed them with `chmod`, but without success.

Comment: is the service process also running python3?  ..... i did not downvote your post, so i suspect that you have not done enough research before you posted your question

Comment: You need to add a bit more info like, what repo and output from log...

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `systemctl cat your.service`.

Answer (score 0):

You only give us stripped information, e.g. with the status of the service and with `chmod`. Executing `sudo chmod ...` must change the permissions, otherwise you don't have a default Raspbian installation. Don't use notepad from MS Windows. There may be an issue with line delimiter **CR+LF** (carriage return + line feed) or encoding not being **UTF-8**. Instead use `editor` on Raspbian. Unix expects as line delimiter only **LF**.

Comment: yeah, chmod is executed as root, I didn't write it becasue is 99% the way to do it. The editor is not classic notepad, but Notepad++ which usually don't break encoding and line ending with different format. By the way I don't think the problem is related to these things, due to the py run smoothly when executed directly, the issue is only when I try to launch it as service.

Comment: @Noisemaker If chmod doesn't work then please use a default Raspbian installation. Nevertheless you should try `editor` on the Raspberry Pi for verification. There may be also an encoding issue with the samba share.